# Magento 2 - Adding custom layout handle for layouts (1 column, 2column etc) set via product admin page

Tags: magento2, layout, event-observer, plugin

I want separate **layout handles** defined for products dependent on their layout  set via the layout options for product within admin (1 column, 2 column left, 2 column right).

I need to set additional instructions to move and remove blocks based on the layout set. For example set a product to 1 column and update the `catalog_product_view_layout_1column.xml` file to remove blocks.

I have tried with both an **observer** and **plugin** to try and set this additional handle however am having difficulty. Below is how I tried to achieve with plugin method:

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View">
    <plugin name="Vendor_Module_LayoutMods" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\LayoutMod" />
</type>
```

> **di.xml**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class LayoutMod
{
    public function aroundinitProductLayout(
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View $subject,
        callable $proceed,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage,
        $product,
        $params = null
    ) {
        $result = $proceed($resultPage, $product, $params);
        $resultPage->addPageLayoutHandles(['layout' => $product->getData('page_layout')], 'catalog_product_view');
        return $result;
    }
}
```

> **plugin/LayoutMod.php**

This seems to add the handle in that `$resultPage->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles()` shows my new custom handle `catalog_product_view_layout_1column` `catalog_product_view_layout_1column.xml` does not seem to be processed.  `catalog_product_view_id_123.xml` does work however fine and blocks are removed. My xml is currently pretty simple as I test:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <attribute name="class" value="my-css-class"/>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.main" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

> **Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view_layout_1column.xml**

I'm wondering can help explain why my new handle is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below seemed to work for me, the key was modifying what was returned:

```
   class LayoutMod
   {
      public function beforeInitProductLayout(
          \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View $subject,
          \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage, 
          \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product, 
          $params = null
      ) {
          $resultPage->addPageLayoutHandles(['layout' => $product->getData('page_layout')], 'catalog_product_view');
          return [$resultPage, $product, $params];
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you solved your issue, but for others coming across this, I'd recommend this article for a full-writeup of how to do this https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/add-custom-layout-handle-to-product-page-magento-2/

Copying relevant content here for posterity's sake:

file: [Vendor][Namespace]\Plugin\Catalog\Product\AddCustomLayoutHandleToProductPlugin.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * @author    Atwix Team
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2018 Atwix (https://www.atwix.com/)
 */
namespace [Vendor]\[Namespace]\Plugin\Catalog\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View as ProductViewHelper;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page as ResultPage;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page;
/**
 *  AddCustomLayoutHandleToProductPlugin
 */
class AddCustomLayoutHandleToProductPlugin
{
    const PRODUCT_LAYOUT_HANDLE = 'product_page_with_custom_handle';
    /**
     * @param  ProductViewHelper $subject
     * @param  Page            $resultPage
     * @param  Product         $product
     * @param  null|DataObject $params
     * @return array
     */
    public function beforeInitProductLayout(
        ProductViewHelper $subject,
        $resultPage,
        $product,
        $params
    ) {
        if ($resultPage instanceof ResultPage && /* your additional checks here */) {
            $resultPage->addHandle([static::PRODUCT_LAYOUT_HANDLE]);
        }
        return [
            $resultPage,
            $product,
            $params
        ];
    }
}
```

file: [Vendor]/[Namespace]/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!--
/**
 * @author Atwix Team
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2018 Atwix (https://www.atwix.com/)
 */-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View">
        <plugin name="add_custom_layout_handle_to_product_page"
                type="[Vendor]\[Namespace]\Plugin\Catalog\Product\AddCustomLayoutHandleToProductPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Based on the `product_page_with_custom_handle` handle name in the class above, you will now be able to create a `product_page_with_custom_handle.xml` file in a theme or module and it should get loaded when the `your additional checks here` logic is satisfied.